# BSON::InvalidObjectId illegal ObjectId format Rails 3.1.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm getting the following error when trying to use the delete method in a Ruby on Rails application.

`BSON::InvalidObjectId in ServicesController#destroy`

I'm using Rails 3.1.1 and MongoDB v2.4.15

Below is the `Delete` link in question.

`%li= link_to 'Delete', @service, :method => :delete, :confirm => "Are you sure you want to delete this service?"`

Here is the log error:

```
Started DELETE "/services/appeals" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-12-21 11:08:42 -0500
Creating scope :orderable_scope. Overwriting existing method Service.orderable_scope.
  Processing by ServicesController#destroy as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"xxx", "id"=>"appeals"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 11ms

BSON::InvalidObjectId (illegal ObjectId format: appeals):
```

When deleting items in other collections it works fine. I'm able to use the "services" edit link without errors. Below is the working `Delete` link and logs for deleting an attorney.

**Working Link**
`%li= link_to "Delete", @attorney, :method => :delete, :confirm => "Are you sure you want to delete this attorney?"`

**Working Log**

```
Started DELETE "/attorneys/first-last" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-12-21 10:37:07 -0500
Creating scope :orderable_scope. Overwriting existing method Attorney.orderable_scope.Processing by AttorneysController#destroy as HTMLParameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"xxx", "id"=>"first-last"}
MONGODB x_development['system.namespaces'].find({})
MONGODB x_development['attorneys'].find({:slug=>"first-last"}).limit(-1).sort([[:_id, :asc]])
MONGODB x_development['system.namespaces'].find({})
MONGODB x_development['users'].find({:_id=>BSON::ObjectId('585a9dbc737da97cbd000006')}).limit(-1).sort([[:_id, :asc]])
Creating scope :orderable_scope. Overwriting existing method Service.orderable_scope.
MONGODB x_development['system.namespaces'].find({})
Redirected to http://0.0.0.0:3000/attorneys
Completed 302 Found in 69ms`
```

It's another developers application that I'm trying to get working correctly again. I'm not very experienced with Ruby, Rails, or MongoDB.

**UPDATE**
Below is the `Full Trace`

```
bson (1.4.0) lib/bson/types/object_id.rb:126:in `from_string'
mongoid (2.4.12) lib/mongoid/fields/internal/object_id.rb:38:in `serialize'
mongoid (2.4.12) lib/mongoid/criterion/optional.rb:97:in `for_ids'
mongoid (2.4.12) lib/mongoid/criteria.rb:310:in `search'
mongoid (2.4.12) lib/mongoid/criterion/inclusion.rb:125:in `find'
mongoid (2.4.12) lib/mongoid/finders.rb:84:in `find'
inherited_resources (1.3.1) lib/inherited_resources/base_helpers.rb:44:in `resource'
cancan (1.6.7) lib/cancan/inherited_resource.rb:11:in `load_resource_instance'
cancan (1.6.7) lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb:32:in `load_resource'
cancan (1.6.7) lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb:25:in `load_and_authorize_resource'
cancan (1.6.7) lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb:10:in `block in add_before_filter'
activesupport (3.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:439:in `_run__3707406960644643515__process_action__1333295842175195574__callbacks'
activesupport (3.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:386:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (3.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.1.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:53:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.1.1) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.1.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:53:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:201:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:193:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:236:in `block in action'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:65:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:65:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:29:in `call'
rack-mount (0.8.3) lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:152:in `block in call'
rack-mount (0.8.3) lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:96:in `block in recognize'
rack-mount (0.8.3) lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:131:in `optimized_each'
rack-mount (0.8.3) lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:95:in `recognize'
rack-mount (0.8.3) lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:141:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:532:in `call'
mongoid (2.4.12) lib/rack/mongoid/middleware/identity_map.rb:33:in `block in call'
mongoid (2.4.12) lib/mongoid.rb:133:in `unit_of_work'
mongoid (2.4.12) lib/rack/mongoid/middleware/identity_map.rb:33:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.3.6) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.3.6) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:35:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:243:in `call'
rack (1.3.6) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:195:in `context'
rack (1.3.6) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:190:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:331:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (3.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:392:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (3.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:68:in `call'
rack (1.3.6) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:101:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:48:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:47:in `call'
railties (3.1.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:13:in `call'
rack (1.3.6) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:24:in `call'
rack (1.3.6) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (3.1.1) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
rack (1.3.6) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:53:in `call'
railties (3.1.1) lib/rails/engine.rb:456:in `call'
railties (3.1.1) lib/rails/rack/content_length.rb:16:in `call'
railties (3.1.1) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.3.6) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
/Users/Home/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
/Users/Home/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
/Users/Home/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'
```

Anyone have any ideas? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the issue is in my `services_controller`

There was a line `before_filter :load_service_by_slug, :only => [:edit, :update, :move_up, :move_down]`

I had to add `:destroy` to that line.